# Getting ORA: 00918 when running a JPA query with two joined table

Tags: oracle, jpa

I want to run this following code:

```
public List<Tab1Attribute> Tab1loadAttribute(EntityManager em, int first, int size)  throws Exception
{
    List<Tab1Attribute> lstTabAttr=null;

    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT "
                 + " ra.*, "
                 + " rc.* " 
                 + " from RS_Tab1_Attribute ra " 
                 + " JOIN RS_Tab2_CHARACTERISTIC rc "
                 + " on ra.item_ref = rc.item_ref "             
                 + " order by ra.item_ref ";

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, "TAB1Attributes");

         List<Object[]> lstQueryResult = query.setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(size).getResultList();


        Tab1Attribute tab1Attr = null;
        Tab2Characteristic tab2Char = null;

        if(lstQueryResult!=null && lstQueryResult.size() > 0)
        {
            lstTab1Attr = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Tab1Attribute>();
        for (Object[] obj : lstQueryResult)
        {
            tab1Attr = (Tab1Attribute) obj[0];
            tab2Char = (Tab2Characteristic) obj[1];
            tabAttr.setTab2Characteristic(tab2Char );

            lstTab1Attr.add(tab1Attr );
        }
        }
            em.clear();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {


        throw e;
    }
    return lstTab1Attr;
}
```

I have two entity classes Tab1Attribute (Table: RS_TAB1_ATTRIBUTE) and Tab2Characteristic(Table: RS_TAB2_CHARACTERISTIC). Tab2Characteristic is a instance variable in Tab1Attribute class (has a relationship). I want to pick the resultSet in  "TAB1Attributes". 
For this I used the following thing on top of the Tab1Attribute class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RS_TAB1_ATTRIBUTE")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "TAB1Attributes", entities = {
@EntityResult(entityClass = com.entity.Tab1Attribute.class),
@EntityResult(entityClass = com.entity.Tab2Characteristic.class)})

public class Tab1Attribute implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="ITEM_REF")
private String itemRef;

/** The v pkg. */
@Transient
private Tab2Characteristic rc;

@Column(name="AC_CA_FI")
private BigDecimal acCaFi;

//other fields and getter setters
```

But when I am running the query using JPA or the above code I am getting ORA: 00918 ,columns ambiguously defined error. If I fetch the whole query result at a single time other then using setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(size) it is running ok.

Please help me on this.

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ambiguity you have to use:

1. Change the names of the columns of table 1.
2. User the `@FieldResult` annotation.

   `@SqlResultSetMapping(name="RS_TAB1_ATTRIBUTE", 
           entities={ 
               @EntityResult(entityClass=com.uk.tui.entity.Tab1Attribute.class, fields={
                   @FieldResult(name="itemRef", column="ITEM_REF_TAB1"),
                   @FieldResult(name="acCaFi", column="AC_CA_FI_TAB1")})
   )`

Comment: thanks... can I just add this @FieldResult to one of the column only which is creating ambiguity . The problem is because of "ITEM_REF" columns which is common in both the tables.

Comment: Yes, You can add it only to conflict column,
if i help you , please baccept my answer and upvot it .

Comment: @FieldResult(name="itemRef", column="ITEM_REF_TAB1") in this "name" is the entity instance variable name and column is my given name. Do I need to do the same thing to the other table also..??

Comment: hey CHHIBI, I am still getting the same error. i have total three matching columns. And I have added three  @FieldResult. like this

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name="RS_TAB1_ATTRIBUTE")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Tab1Attributes", entities = {
@EntityResult(entityClass = com.entity.Tab1Attribute.class,
fields={ @FieldResult(name="ItemReference", column="ITEM_REF_TAB1"),    @FieldResult(name="sType", column="S_TYPE_TAB1"),
@FieldResult(name="sYear", column="S_YEAR_TAB1")}),
@EntityResult(entityClass = com.entity.RoomCharacteristic.class,
fields={ @FieldResult(name="ItemReference", column="ITEM_REF_TAB2"), @FieldResult(name="sType", column="S_TYPE_TAB2"),
@FieldResult(name="sYear", column="S_YEAR_TAB2")})})